# How to select integer and decimal numbers from a string (XSLT, XPath)

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath-2.0

I have a function in XSLT that takes from a string the integer numbers.

> Blockquote Ex: Input: income 200 addback 600
>       Output: 200 600.

I what to change the function to diplay the first integer or decimal number in the string:

> Blockquote Ex: Input: income 200.20 addback 12.4
>   Output: 200.20

Now it diplay:

> Output: 200 20  12 4

What i need to change in the function for the desired outcome?

```
<xsl:function name="fn:trimNumber" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
        <xsl:sequence select=
            "for $i in tokenize($pStr, '[^0-9]+')[.]
            return xs:integer($i)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use backreferences in the `tokenize` function? Then you could use `^[^0-9]+[+-]?(\d*\.?\d+).*$` regex and replace with `$1`

Comment: If you use `xsl:analyze-string` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) instead of tokenize and then use a regular expression to match on the integer and decimal format you expect instead of on the separators you should be able to extract the numbers easily.

Comment: I will inform about analyze-string.

Comment: What about `<xsl:variable name="resval" select=
      "tokenize(replace($pStr, '^[^0-9]+[+-]?(\d*\.?\d+).*$', '$1'), ' ')"/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. In your function, evaluate this XPath 2.0 expression:** (you will need to replace the 1st argument of `replace()` which is now `.`, with the parameter name used in the declaration of the function-- such as $pText):

```
replace(., '^(([\.-]?[^\d\.-])+)?([+-]?\d*\.?\d+).*$', '$3')
```

**Here is a complete example**:

**XML document**:

```
<t>
   <line>income great. 13 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
   <line>income great. 3.14 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
   <line>income great. .55 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
   <line>income great. -13 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
   <line>income great. -3.14 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
   <line>income great. -.55 addback 12.4 xxxx 1.23</line>
</t>
```

**XSLT transformation** -- needed just to output the result of evaluating the XPath expression above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^(([\.-]?[^\d\.-])+)?([+-]?\d*\.?\d+).*$', '$3')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   13
   3.14
   .55
   -13
   -3.14
   -.55
```

---

II. **If you can use XPath 3.0**, use the standard XPath 3.0 function:

[**analyze-string()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-analyze-string)

Comment: Thank you Dimitre Novatchev, It was exactly what I looked for.